# заполнение TlvDbGrid

Tags: delphi, radstudio

Всем привет.
Как программно добавить строки в Grid?

Функция по клику:

```
 procedure TfmZayava.btVoditelAddClick(Sender: TObject);
    begin //Добавить водителя в заявку
    dbgVoditel.SetFocus;//Для корректного сохранения данных ЗПУ
    If DM1.qrSvZayavaPrvTmp.RecordCount=0
       then begin
            unFunction.AlarmViewGB(fmZayava.gbPrvz);
            Exit;
            end;
    
    fmManagerSelect.btSelect.Visible:=True;
    fmManagerSelect.Tag:=2;//метка выбора водителя
    fmManagerSelect.ShowModal;
 end;
```

Как при клике добавлять строчку добавить в строчку и и заполнить данные в таблице введенные в другой форме?

Пробовал делать так хотябы просто добавить строчку. Не работает

```
dbgVoditel.DataSource.DataSet.Append;
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Хочу дополнить свой вопрос.

Сравнивая и анализируя другие таблицы понял как они заполняется.
Посмотрел какие поля нужны и заполнил **DataSourse**. После этого стало все отображаться.

Но Я не совсем понял, а как Мне Свой запрос на вывод добавить?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Выбрал Источник.

Сам источник тут.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Все стало выводится работает как и должно.
Но, осталась третья таблица на форме, и не один источник к ней не подходит. Как бы Мне его написать самому?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

Как я понял ты работаешь с базой данных через DbGrid.
к примеру тут https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48615105/create-empty-row-in-dbgrid рекомендуют `Query1.InsertRecord([null, null, null, null]);`, т.е. любым доступным тебе методом добавляешь строку в БД. Может у тебя какие-то ограничения в БД (например какое-нибудь поле обязательно должно быть не пустым или уникальным)?

Comment: Спасибо за комментарий. В базе у же есть значения, через хранимую процедуру их записываю и получаю. А вот в TlvDbGrid Я их не вижу. Хочу выгрузить.  `dbgVoditel. ` Через точку методы вообще на добавление не нашел. `dbgVoditel.InsertRecord([something1, something2, something3, something4]);` верно понял?